# Error in creating subclasses in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class=sticky>
    <li>
        text1
    </li>
    <li>
        text 2
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.sticky ul li:nth-child(even) a {
    -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    background: #cfc;
}
.sticky ul li:nth-child(3n) a {
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

But it's not working.. Please help me to correct it.
Thanks in advance

jsfiddle for the above code 
http://jsfiddle.net/cZRg6/

Comment: Can you show us the HTML, and make a jsfiddle?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't provide the html you are trying to select?

Comment: Ok sorry, please check it out now

Comment: @VaisakhCp: In your jsfiddle you haven't any `a`-tag...

Comment: @dTDesign I have included it now..still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.sticky already is the **ul**

```
  .sticky li:nth-child(even), a {  

  .sticky li:nth-child(3n), a {
```

and you need at least 3 elements if you're using nth-child(3n), and I can't see no anchor in your fiddle.

if you include an anchor in the `<li>` elements remove the commas

```
  .sticky li:nth-child(even) a {  

  .sticky li:nth-child(3n) a {
```